# aligning text and images with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to learning bootstrap for web development and am designing a webpage that has a section that will be split by 2 different colors with an image in the middle covering both of the colored sections and a form on the right-hand side.

these are the colors and how the section is split:

[image]

this is the code I have so far.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed);

div.container-fluid
{
    background-color: blue;
    padding-left: 150px;
}
div.container-fluid_1
{
    background-color: #75838C;
    height: 450px;
}
h2
{
    color: white;
    size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;    
    
}
p
{
    color: white;
    size: 14;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
    <div class="page">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="twristband">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <h2>the heading for the text below</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <p>this will have a bit of text here</p>
            </div>        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid_1">
        <div class="bwristband">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <h2>Hello</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

any help would be appreciated with this as at the moment I have split the section but the other color doesn't display and currently have no idea how I would add the image to the page

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: how do I go about creating a code snippet for the question that I have posted?

Comment: There's a link in my comments.

Comment: the code snippet has been created